# Trouble with installing pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am new to python and I read online that pip is a good tool to install. I searched online on how to install pip and the first step listed was to check if python was installed properly by opening cmd in admin mode and typing `python` and it took me to the Microsoft store. I searched online about this and I followed some guide to editing PATH  but it did not work. Some other posts said to try typing `py` and it worked. Then I followed the guide to install a file called `get-pip.py`. I downloaded it, went into cmd and into the directory where it was downloaded, and typed `python get-pip.py` and the command prompt just skipped one line. Now I tried `pip -V` and cmd did not recognize it. So I tried moved the `get-pip.py` file into where my `python.exe` file existed and tried `py get-pip.exe` and got the error `C:\Users\[*myname*]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Any help would be appreciated and sorry if this has already been asked I couldn't find good solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: pip is in \Python37\Scripts directory

Comment: I found the files! There are 3 files in there called pip, pio3 and pip3.8. I double-clicked them, and some cmd-type window opened and I still am not able to execute the `pip -V` command

Answer (score 1):

You could use the python installer fitting your system ([download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/)) and click change installation.

Answer (score 0):

if you are new start using `Google Colab` first to learn how to code in python most of the packages are already installed and no need to install the basic packages

Answer (score 0):

you may either:

1. include your pip location (\Python37\Scripts) into PATH; or
2. call pip by typing whole path, like `\Python37\Scripts\pip -v`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install ***pip*** is with modifying the python installation.

Step 1 - Open Apps & Features

Step 2 - Find Python and click on it

Step 3 - Press Modify

Step 4 - Select ***pip***

Step 5 - Select Add Python to environment variables and install everything

That will install ***pip*** and add it to your environment variables so you can run pip task in command prompt or powershell from anywhere.